# Teamcity build fails with roslyn error

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, teamcity, roslyn

I am trying to build a sln I have on TeamCity and I am getting the following error

```
[Csc] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\Radius.Infrastructure.Conversion.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output CustomLException.cs DT.cs OldDT.cs IDT.cs IRS.cs ISRVS.cs SRV.cs RS.cs LT.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs SRVS.cs "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
[18:20:51][Csc] Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn
[18:20:54][Csc] DT.cs(1, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GuerrillaNtp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[18:20:54][Csc] OldDT.cs(1, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServiceStack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[18:20:54][Csc] RS.cs(1, 14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'Radius' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
[18:20:54][Csc] RS.cs(2, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServiceStack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[18:20:54][Csc] SRVS.cs(1, 14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'Radius' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
[18:20:54][Csc] SRVS.cs(2, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServiceStack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have latest MsBuild Tools installed `Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET Framework` and I cannot understand why it fails

Comment: Those are missing nuget packages? Did you run restore before build?